# Excel Comparing dates with floor not working correctly

Tags: excel, time, logic, floor

I am trying to compare a date and time to an date and hour slot. When comparing With floor they are not the same although appear the same

I am trying to compare a date and time to an date and hour slot.
Eg, comparing a time of A

```
  1
A 14/04/2023 15:20
B 14/04/2023 15:00
```

I was using if `A1<=B1`, but when there are minutes as in this example it misses it out, so I used `floor(A1,"1:00")<-B1` and it is still not working.

If I look at value of each they l0ok that same, but subtracting they are not and logicall they are not. What is going on

Cells example

[image]

Formulas example

[image]

Comment: Excel will store up to 15 sig digits.  That means that a minute has a spread of `+/-0.000347222222222222`   In other words typing in the hour may not return an exact double of doing floor.  If you want to truly match you will need to round both to the hour.

Comment: Thanks Scott, rounding both gets it to work